# ¿Cómo dividir y reordenar el contenido dentro de la etiqueta ((PERS)) por ' y ' o ' y)' usando expresiones regulares de Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, split

```py
import re

input_text = "((PERS) Marcos Sy y) ((PERS) Lucy) estuvieron ((VERB) jugando) sdds" #example 1
input_text = "ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María y Rosa ds) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas" #example 2

input_text = re.sub(
                    r"\(\(PERS\)" + r"((?:\w\s*)+(?:\sy\s(?:\w\s*)+)+)(?=\s*y\s*(?:\)|\())",
                    #lambda m: (f"((PERS)){m[1]}) y"),
                    lambda m: (f"((PERS)){m[1].replace(' y', ') y ((PERS)')}"),
                    input_text, re.IGNORECASE)

print(input_text) # --> output
```

Necesito separar el contenido dentro de una etiqueta `((PERS) )` si hay una `" y "` o una `" y)"` en el medio.
Así que saca la `" y"` o la `" y "` de la etiqueta `((PERS) )` y el resto del contenido (en caso de que se encuentre como en el caso del `ejemplo 2`) dejarlo en otra etiqueta `((PERS) )`. Pruebo con `\s+y\s+?` y con `\s+y\s+`

Para lograr el resultado deseado, probé con una expresión regular para hacer coincidir todos los nombres dentro de la etiqueta `((PERS) )` que están separados por `" y "` o `" y)"`. Para eso, traté de usar una búsqueda anticipada positiva para buscar `" y "` o `" y)"` después de cada nombre, y luego agrupé todos los nombres. Pero esta búsqueda anticipada no funciona bien.

Entonces deberia obtener este output para cada uno de los ejemplos respectivamente:

```
"((PERS) Marcos Sy) y ((PERS) Lucy) estuvieron ((VERB) jugando) sdds" #for example 1

"ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María) y ((PERS)Rosa ds) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas" #for example 2
```

Comment: @DanteS. Estaba usando unos labels de este formato `((PERS) texto )` , la idea es que no halla mas de un nombre dentro de cada label, entonces el criterio es que si hay un `" y "` o un `" y)"` entonces se lo excluya del label, ya que no es parte del nombre (o es texto perteneciente a otro nombre distinto. Lo que yo intente es usar un look-ahead, creo que podria usarlo de tamaño limitado si en lugar de poner `r"\s+y\s+(?:\)|)"` pusiese `r" y "` y `r" y\)"` , en ese caso podria tener el mismo criterio de delimitacion pero con longitud fija, de modo que ya el uso del look-ahead sería viable

Comment: `"((PERS)something_a y something_b)"` debería quedar como `"((PERS)something_a) y ((PERS)something_b)"` , y para el caso de `((PERS)something_a y)` debería quedar `((PERS)something_a) y` , creo que podria hacerse usando un look-ahead de tamaño fijo

Comment: Gracias por el esfuerzo. La pregunta está clarísima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos con una expresión que coincida con ambos casos:

```
\(\(PERS\) +([^) ]+(?: +[^) ]+)*?) +y\b *([^)]*)\)
#            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^
#                1ra persona               2da
```

En donde tenemos 2 grupos (paréntesis)

1. El patrón que coincide con la primera persona `[^) ]+(?: +[^) ]+)*?` que busca coincidir con cualquier palabra formada por caracteres que no sean espacios ni un cierre de paréntesis, seguido de más palabras opcionales (misma lógica, que no sean espacios ni paréntesis), pero repetido lo menos posible así a continuación nos da lugar a coincidir con  `y`.
2. La segunda persona `[^)]*`, todo lo que está antes del cierre del paréntesis.

Lo importante es que la segunda persona puede coincidir con cualquier texto, pero también coincide si no hay nada. Entonces, en la función usada para el reemplazo, si no está la segunda persona, vamos a reemplazar por

```
"((PERS) 1ra persona) y"
```

pero si coincidió con algún texto en la segunda persona, vamos a reemplazar por

```
"((PERS) 1ra persona) y ((PERS) 2da)"
```

La clave está acá, en la **función de reemplazo**, usando textos diferentes según lo que haya coincidido con el segundo grupo `m[2]`

```
f" ((PERS) {m[2]})" if m[2] else ""
```

**Código**:

```
import re

ejemplos = [
    "((PERS) Marcos Sy y) ((PERS) Lucy) estuvieron ((VERB) jugando) sdds", #example 1
    "ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María y Rosa ds) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas" #example 2
]

for input_text in ejemplos:
    resultado = re.sub(
        r"\(\(PERS\) +([^) ]+(?: +[^) ]+)*?) +y\b *([^)]*)\)",
        lambda m: 
            "((PERS) {}) y{}"
            .format(
                m[1],
                f" ((PERS) {m[2]})" if m[2] else ""
            ),
        input_text,
        re.I
    )

    print(resultado)
```

**Resultado**:

```
((PERS) Marcos Sy) y ((PERS) Lucy) estuvieron ((VERB) jugando) sdds

ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María) y ((PERS) Rosa ds) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas
```

Comment: Realmente muchas gracias por la ayuda y todo el detalle de la explicación